# postfix truncating users full name in sent email

Tags: postfix

**Issue:** I have a RHEL server that sends alerts under active directory user IDs.
Everything works, emails are sent by the RHEL server and received by the recipients . . except the users full name shows just the Surname.
I have tested this in scripts with commands: mail, mailx, mutt and mutt as a client, issue is present in all.
Our Windows AD name format is "Surname, Firstname" and the RHEL server sees this:

```
# getent passwd csullivan
csullivan:*:1367239261:1367200513:Sullivan, Chris:/home/csullivan:/bin/bash
```

The recipient sees an email coming from

```
Sullivan <csullivan@server01.company.com>
```

The full name is cut at the comma.
It should read "**Sullivan, Chris** <csullivan@server01.company.com>"

I can simulate this with a local user (not on AD) on the server so this is clearly postfix cutting off the full name at the comma.
Removal of the comma for the local users full name in /etc/passwd then passes the full name with spaces.

How do I allow acceptance of a comma in the in full name in postfix?